# HTML visibilty doesn’t work

Tags: html, asp.net

Hi guys I am trying to create some divs which will be transparent.
Here is my code:

```
   <div id="ShopMenu">
           <center><ul class="shopul">
                 <li style="margin-left:12%" class="shopli"><a href="../index.aspx">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>            
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="UpNewBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtnActive" ID="UpNewBtn" runat="server" Text="Recent updates" /></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="VehiclesBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtn" ID="VehiclesBtn" runat="server" Text="Vehicles & transportation" /></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="SportsBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtn" ID="SportsBtn" runat="server" Text="Sports" /></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="TechBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtn" ID="TechBtn" runat="server" Text="Tech & gadgets" /></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="ClothingBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtn" ID="ClothingBtn" runat="server" Text="Clothing & accessories" /></li>
                 <li class="shopli"><asp:Button OnClick="SearchApearBtn_Click" CssClass="shoptxtbtn" ID="SearchApearBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" /></li>
           </ul></center> 
            <div id="UpNewDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div visible="false"  id="VehiclesDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div visible="false"  id="SportsDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div visible="false"  id="TechDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div visible="false"  id="ClothingDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
            <div visible="false"  id="SearchDiv" class="shopbox"><br /><br /><br /></div>
       </div>
```

and it is not handeled on the screen. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please try to edit it so people have an easier time answering your question

Comment: the divs which should not be visible are visible what is the problem why are they visible?

Comment: I don't see any relevant CSS anywhere and you haven't posted any relevant CSS files or anything. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: there is no needed css its about the line visible=false which is not working i mean that i can see all the six div instead of 1

Comment: if you mean a server side `visible` attribute then you must add `runat="server"` to your `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Oz, 
If I'm understanding the question correctly You could try using styling for this:

Instead of:  `visible="false"`
Try:         `style="display:none;"`

Hope this helps.